# redirect after j_spring_security_check

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I was able to get spring security everything to work with the following:

```
<http access-denied-page="/start.jsf">
    <intercept-url pattern="/start.jsf" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/web/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/start.jsf" default-target-url="/web/user/homepage.jsf"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.jsf?state=failure"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsf?state=logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.myapp.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

My question is for the class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler, after it authenticates, it just stays as a blank white page. I can redirect to the default homepage with the context.redirect(), but is there a way for it to goto the default homepage automatically? I even have it listed in the spring xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the reasons why this may not work is because your **com.myapp.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler** does not extend **org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler** or any other authentication handler that internally redirects on #onAuthenticationSuccess.

You can get it to work without manually redirecting by having your service extend one that does it for you. For example...

```
@Service("authenticationSuccessHandler")
public class WebAuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //do your work here then call super so it redirects accordingly
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `default-target-url` attribute and add the following:

```
<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.myapp.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/web/user/homepage.jsf"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Spring security documentation says that when a custom authentication success handler is used, then you have to remove the attribute and set the target in your handler.

Comment: That didn't work. But I was able to get it to work only with redirect. I'm basically passing in the url that I want to use from the bean.